# Select Comment with xPath by Comment-Text

Tags: xpath

How can I select the next node after an defined comment? I know the text of the comment and need the next nodes.

Best regards
Christoph

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a solution. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Supposing the comment is a child of the current node**, and the comment's text is `"comment-text"`, then the following XPath expression selects the first element (sibling) that follows the comment node:

```
comment()[. = 'comment-text'][1]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

If we want the following element to be selected (regardless if it is sibling of the comment or not), the corresponding XPath expression is:

```
comment()[. = 'comment-text'][1]/following::*[1]
```